# something like modules in orchard project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

As you know, in ASP.NET MVC you can use Areas to categories your application and make it easy to manage and organize your logic.Say if I have controller named "Teams" and action named "Create", which is located in "Fun" Area, then I can request the action as follow:

http://myapplication.com/fun/teams/create

This is very nice feature, But it does not allow nested Areas. In fact I want to know how orchard project used it modules like areas.Interesting point is that almost every module has it own route handling class.

How All these have been implemented ?